# Swift iOS AVVideoCapturePreviewLayer resolves to nil

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

In the viewDidLoad() section of my code I have this

```
    let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    previewView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
```

however when it is called in here it resolves to nil in the compiler:

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!,didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!,fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    autoreleasepool {
        let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!

        let formatDescription = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer)!
        self.currentVideoDimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(formatDescription)
        self.currentSampleTime = CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)


        // CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0)
        // let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0)
        // let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0)
        // let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0)
        // let lumaBuffer = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0)
        //
        // let grayColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
        // let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(lumaBuffer, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, grayColorSpace, CGBitmapInfo.allZeros)
        // let cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)
        var outputImage = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: imageBuffer)

        if self.filter != nil {

            self.filter.setValue(outputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            outputImage = self.filter.outputImage!
        }
        let orientation = UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation
        var t: CGAffineTransform!
        if orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait {
            t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(-M_PI / 2.0))
        } else if orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown {
            t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI / 2.0))
        } else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight) {
            t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI))
        } else {
            t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0)
        }
        outputImage = outputImage.imageByApplyingTransform(t)

        let cgImage = self.context.createCGImage(outputImage, fromRect: outputImage.extent)
        self.ciImage = outputImage

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {


            self.previewLayer.contents = cgImage


        })
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why? my suspicion is that the previewLayer is created before the captureSession is instantiated, however i placed the captureSession.startRunning code in my viewDidAppear() function and it still caused a nil value. I currently have it in the viewDidLoad section now. If anyone could help it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please share the code where you setup your session and input/output devices.

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning to `previewLayer` property.

```
let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
previewView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
```

is supposed to be

```
previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
previewView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
```

Comment: so then I would need to declare the variable var previewLayer:CALayer!

Comment: Yeah you can declare a constant and assign both `self.previewLayer` and your constant to the same thing, but I'd just use `self.previewLayer` everywhere.

Comment: @Onicha21 please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: @Adeel I am unsure how to do this could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Adeel I meant please elaborate how to accept this answer

Comment: There's he a tick ✅ mark on the left side. Just click on it. It'll turn Green.